# Why Vue 3 ref is not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, ref, vue-reactivity

I have searched this issue and tried all the things but did not work for me. I am using Vue 3 ref and it needs to be updated after calling the Axios with the response but it is not getting updated here is some piece of code.

> Here invite_link is an object

```
const props = defineProps({
   'workplace': Object 
  });

// Also tried const workplace = props.workplace;

const workplace = ref(props.workplace);
axios.post(url).then(res=>{
  workplace.value.invite_link = res.data.workplace.invite_link
});
```

and in the template I am using `v-show="workplace.invite_link"` that needs to be shown after Axios ran successfully. I have also check Vue devtools and it still shows the old workplace object

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. The problem is specific to the parts that you omitted. It generally shouldn't be done the way you did it, the restriction on prop mutation is there for a reason, https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow

Answer (score 3):

```
const workplace = ref(props.workplace);
```

It is important to understand that `setup` is executed only once in component lifecycle. The code above creates a ref and INITIALISE it with the current value of `props.workplace`. The value of such ref will never ever change.

If you want to create a ref which value will update whenever `props.workplace` updates (which is almost always what you want), do this:

```
const { workplace } = toRefs(props);
```

or

```
const workplace = toRef(props, 'workplace');
```

[Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#accessing-props)

Comment: I have already tired toRef but when I tried to change the value of workplace after axios it does not update